# Silverlight 3 BETA DataGrid grouping

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

NB this was for the silverlight 3 beta, RTM seems to handle grouping entirely differently.

I've a grid that is working fine, which I'm using the GroupDescriptions property like so:

```
<data:DataGrid.GroupDescriptions>
    <cm:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ClientName" />
</data:DataGrid.GroupDescriptions>
```

This works brilliantly, it's only when the datagrid is rendered, it shows the grouping by "ClientName". Obviously I'd like that to be "Client Name". I cannot for the life of me see a property that would allow me to set this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW this has changed in SL3 RTM:

Silverlight 3 Beta

[Xaml]

```
<dataGrid.GroupDescriptions>

      <windata:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName=”State” />

</dataGrid.GroupDescriptions>
```

Silverlight 3 RTM

[c#]

```
pagedCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(“State”));
```

You need to use the PagedCollectionView class to accomplish this, it can't be done in Xaml anymore.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(VS.95).aspx

And from that link, here's how to change the text in the group header:

When items are grouped in the DataGrid, each group has a header. You can change the appearance of the DataGridRowGroupHeader by defining a custom Style and adding it to the RowGroupHeaderStyles collection. If you have multiple levels of grouping, you can apply different styles to each group level. Styles are applied in the order in which they are defined. For example, if you define two styles, the first will be applied to top level row groups. The second style will be applied to all row groups at the second level and lower. The DataContext of the DataGridRowGroupHeader is the CollectionViewGroup that the header represents.

So a quick and dirty example would be:

```
<dataControls:DataGrid x:Name="Grid">
    <dataControls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
        <Style TargetType="dataControls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="My text."/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
   </dataControls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</dataControls:DataGrid>
```

In practice you probably want to include the other control parts that are specified for DataGridRowGroupHeader so that you can expand and collapse them.  As with everything WPF, instead of just setting a "GroupText" property you have to go whole 9 yards!

Comment: what is the paged collection view? I tried using the CollectionViewSource and the GroupDescriptions property is not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem as DaRKoN_ and having read James Cadd insightful answer I solved my own problem. By using Blend I have extracted the template for the `DataGridRowGroupHeader`. You can use the code below to customize it:

```
<data:DataGrid>
  <data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    <Style TargetType="data:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="data:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                  <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                          <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Stroke).Color" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                          </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                          <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Stroke).Color" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                          </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                          <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5"/>
                          </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                      </VisualStateGroup>
                      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                          <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                          </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                      </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="CollapsedArrow" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="#FF414345" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="5" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 0,1 L .6,.5 L 0,0 Z"/>
                    <Path x:Name="ExpandedArrow" Fill="#FF414345" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6" Data="F1 M 0,1 L 1,1 L 1,0 L 0,1 Z"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
              <dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
              </dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Regular"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              </dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
              <Rectangle Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Height="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
              <Rectangle x:Name="IndentSpacer" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
              <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Height="15" Margin="2,0,0,0" Width="15" Template="{StaticResource ToggleButtonTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
              <StackPanel Margin="0,1,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <TextBlock x:Name="PropertyNameElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding PropertyNameVisibility}"/>

                <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountElement" Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ItemCountVisibility}"/>
              </StackPanel>
              <Rectangle Fill="#FFD3D3D3" Height="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="2"/>
              <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
              <dataPrimitives:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" Grid.RowSpan="3" dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
            </dataPrimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</data:DataGrid>
```

I have added blank lines before and after the `TextBlock` that contains the offending text. You can completely turn it off by using the following XAML:

```
<data:DataGrid>
   <data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
     <Style TargetType="data:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
       <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
     </Style>
  <data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</data:DataGrid>
```

If you want to modify the text you will have both remove the name of the `TextBlock` and add a `Text` attribute:

```
<TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding PropertyNameVisibility}" Text="Client Name:"/>
```

The `DataGridRowGroupHeader` will look for a `TextBlock` named `PropertyNameElement` and set the text from code, and to avoid that happening you will have to remove the name from the template.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the template graciously provided by Martin Liversage (thanks!) but I can't seem to control the height of the group data row.  Adjusting the size of the rectangles etc just takes up more room in the row, hiding other parts.  It seems the row height is being controlled by the container for the row, outside the influence of the template.
TIA
Toby

Found the answer!
Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075(VS.95).aspx
This defines all the control styles and templates and zooming into the DataGrid and viewing the Default Template you will find:

```
<data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
<Style TargetType="local:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE4E8EA" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
     ...snip...
     </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
</data:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
```

Setting the Height property does the job.

Comment: I spent about 5 minutes trying to figure out how to get the default template using Blend, then I just opened Reflector and extracted generic.xaml from the assembly's resources. Microsoft really has to come up with a better solution for this, bunch of daft pri...

Answer (score 0):

Set the Name property of the Display attribute applied to the property you're grouping by:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display( Name = "My Property" )]
public string MyProperty {get;set;}
```

looking at the Display class, one might think GroupName would be the property you set, but alas it it not.

I understand 'muddying up' the model with display data isn't always how everyone (myself included) likes to do things .. but in contrast to the amount of work required to do it in the above ways .. I think it wins out this time.